# Android started and bound service not persistent when unbinding and app kill

Tags: android, service

I have a two part problem with started and bound service.

I have a started and bound service that updates gps locations to an api. The service is started and stopped by a button in an activity.

I have a map activity to show the current location updates from the gps. The map activity is bound to the service via bindService(). I am using messenger to receive data from the service.

The service works correctly upto the point where it is bound to the map activity when the activity is opened. The activity is supposed to unbind from the service when it is destroyed and the service should live on.

The problem is that the service is killed along with the activity when it is destroyed and sometimes it is not (I dont know why). I have unbindService() implemented in ondestroy() of the activity.

The second part is that the service should live on even when the app is removed from the task manager.
I have started it as a foreground service, it does not work.
I tried implementing the service in a remote process and it works, but the code I used to check if the service is running or not returns null (I need this part too).
I tried re-starting it as foreground service in onTaskRemoved(), it does not work.

If there are any decent tutorials on started and bound services, I'm up for that too.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)      getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: foreground services are not likely to be killed (just like std music player service), so what does not work when calling `startForeground` ?

Comment: As I mentioned when the app is killed by swiping off from the recents tab, the service is killed too.

Comment: tried `android:process=":remoteservice"` and `startForeground`?

Comment: yes.. i did.. it works but the code check for running services returned null for the service, which is why i am not using it.

Comment: what check? what do you need it for?

Comment: i need to check if the service is running or not for another part of the app...

Comment: what for? just start it anyway, it will not make any difference how many times you will call `startService`

Comment: i don't need to start it.. i just need to see if it is running or not.

Comment: you dont need a started service? i am a bit lost as your title states: `Android started and bound service [...]`

Comment: I am starting the service....i need to check the service running or not for different part of the app

Comment: see [his](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/jEvXMWgbgzE): `We deliberately don't have an API to check whether a service is 
running because, nearly without fail, when you want to do something 
like that you end up with race conditions in your code.` , so again: why do you need to check if it is running or not?

Comment: maybe i wasnt clear enough, I need to start and stop a service from an activity. And I need to bind another activity to it. And lastly i need to switch a ui element on or off in  a third activity depending upon the service running or not.

Comment: my last comment quoted Dianne Hackborn: a lead engineer at android team, so if you need a test if a service is running you have most likely an app architecture error